# Matching a variable to a list and save the match

Tags: python

newbie question,I have the following code where I need to match the data in variable gerrit with the list gerrit_refs and get the corresponding match and save in a variable,how can I do that?

```
'''
gerrit_refs:
refs/changes/89/202089/4
refs/changes/39/205739/2
refs/changes/94/195594/6
refs/changes/90/202090/4
refs/changes/92/202092/4
'''

def main ():
    gerrit=205739
    with open('gerrit_refs.txt', 'r') as f:
        # Here we make a list of refs based on the file
        gerrit_refs = [line.strip() for line in f]
    match = None
    for ref in gerrit_refs:
        if gerrit in ref:
            match = ref
            print match
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not in

Comment: Why are you opening the file in binary mode (with 'rb' instead of 'r')? Seems like this file just contains ASCII characters.

Comment: @NickODell - I updated with what I tried ,which is giving a compilation error

Comment: @user1927396 Are you sure that's the entire error message?

Comment: The `in` operator, when used with strings, searches for a substring. Since the `gerrit` variable is an integer, it is being asked to look for an integer in a string, which is an error. As illustrated in my answer, the `gerrit` variable needs to be a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out matching lines in your list comprehension:

```
def main ():
    gerrit = 205739
    gerrit_str = str(gerrit)
    with open('gerrit_refs.txt', 'rb') as f:
        # Here we make a list of refs based on the file
        gerrit_refs = [line.strip() for line in f if gerrit_str in line]

    if gerrit_refs:
        # At least one match was found.
        print gerrit_refs
```

Note the need to change the `gerrit` search variable to a string. The `in` operator doesn't work with mixed variables.

This will work if there are multiple references as it returns a list. If you just want to grab the first match, then simply extract the first item:

```
if gerrit_refs:
    print "First match:", gerrit_refs[0]
```

Comment: above code output is in list format like ['refs/changes/39/205739/2'],output should be like refs/changes/39/205739/2 ,please provide inputs

Comment: Updated my answer - its just a matter of extracting the first element from a list.

Comment: I dont want to convert gerrit to a string,is there a way to make modifications and keep as gerrit = 205739 instead of gerrit = "205739"

Comment: Not really since at some point you have to do a string search (even the regular expression answer has to make a string out of it). If its a big problem, leave `gerrit` as an integer, and create a string copy `gerrit_str = str(gerrit)` which you then use to search with. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
next((l.strip() for l in open('gerrit_refs.txt') if str(gerrit) in l), False)
```